# Burning CD stuck at 100% Creating image checksum

Tags: 13.04, cd, burning

Burning data CD using brasero get stuck at 100% and the dialog box only show Creating image checksum, empty progress bar, and a cancel button, and the disk is not spinning anymore in my cd writer. Simply click cancel will make the cd blank, i have try with some new an used CD-RW disc but stilk no luck. I'm on Raring.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with brasero. You can try using K3b. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/k3b/

Comment: I ll give K3b a try

Comment: Six years later, this defect is still not solved.

Answer (score 5):

**First solution:**

Just disable the checksum: **Open Brasero > Edit > Plugins > Uncheck Image Checksum.**

**Second solution:**

Install **cdrdao** and this should solve the problem. Unfortunately, it can't solve it in the middle of the burning process.

```
sudo apt-get install cdrdao
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, still stuck at 100% even when checksum is disabled but this time my CD keep spinning in the drive. Looks like my CD writer isn't compatible with Ubuntu, guess I better buy a new one, modern hardware tends to work better in Linux.

Comment: On the other place someone suggested to use k3b. But that's already becomes too far from simply using the native apps...

Comment: I can't believe but this happens with external USB based burner on 16.04...

Answer (score 2):

k3b has been a standard on my machines for over a decade.  It just works (TM).  I was having the same problem with Brasero/gnome CD creator and just installed it.  Problem solved.

The nice thing about Linux is it doesn't really matter what desktop/native environment you have, you can use applications from others.  apt/yum will install all the needed libraries.